# Irreducible affine algebraic varieties corresponds to prime ideals

Tags: algebraic-geometry, maximal-and-prime-ideals, affine-varieties

> If $V$ is an irreducible affine variety, then $I(V)$ is prime.

A quick search on the site, I have found questions on the other direction (prime ideals implies irreducibility) but not in this direction.

I have translated the defintion of irreducibility to a condition on ideals: if $V_1$ and $V_2$ are subvarieties of $V$ such that $I(V) =I(V_1)\cap I(V_2)$, then $I(V)$ equals to $I(V_1)$ or $I(V_2)$.

Now to show that it is a prime ideal, suppose $fg\in I(V)$. My idea is to construct two ideals where each contains one of $f$ and $g$. I have tried putting $I_1 = I(V(f) \cap V) $ and so on but it doesn't work so far. Any hint on how I could continue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: $V(fg)=V(f)\cup V(g)$ and $V=V\cap V(fg)=(V(f)\cap V)\cup (V(g)\cap V)$. This implies that $V(f)\cap V=V$ or $V(g)\cap V=g$.

Comment: I knew it would have a simple answer. Somehow I didn't think about working with varieties instead of dealing ideals. And since I'm new to it, it's slightly confusing at times. Thanks for the answer :)